# Home directory tilde symbol replaced with minus symbol

Tags: command-line, directory

Trivial but annoying thing with my Ubuntu system. My tilde (~) symbol representing my home directory has been replaced with the minus (-) symbol. It works on the command line as part of the path, e.g, if I want to go to my home directory I can type cd ~ and get there. It is just that my path is displayed as mike@mike:-$

Any idea how to restore ~ to represent home in my path?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change something in your prompt ?

From `man bash`: "PS1  The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string."

You can echo the content of PS1 with:
`echo $PS1`
and then you can try to change it with typing
`PS1='\h:$(pwd) (\w) -> '`
where

- `\h` : the hostname up to the first ‘.’
- `$(pwd)` : the working directory
- `\w` : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde

If the latest command restore your tilde, you can check in `~/.bashrc` for the PS1 definition (if your shell is bash).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My $PS1 is: 
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
so the \w is what turns into the minus (-) were as I want my tilde back.

Comment: Hey, I saw on [this website](https://www.semipol.de/2010/12/30/bash-home-directory-not-replaced-with-tilde.html) that you should check the value of the path of your home directory in the `/etc/passwd`, as "somewhere in the bash-internals a check tests whether the output of pwd matches the contents of $HOME"

Comment: Sometimes we have to fess up to doing something stupid and that time is now for me. The font on my term is such that my poor eyes couldn't see the difference between ~ and -. ponsfrilus thanks for taking the time to help and I've learned several things from your advice.